# Find elements in one RDD but not in ther other RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have two JavaRDD A and B. I want to only keep longs that are in A but not in B. How should I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a solution in scala. Should be almost similar in Java.

Do a `leftOuterJoin` which would give all the records in the first rdd alongwith matching records from the second rdd. Like `WrappedArray((168,(def,None)), (192,(abc,Some(abc))))`. But to keep the record only present in first rdd, we apply a filter over `None`.

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((192, "abc"),(168, "def")))
val data2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((192, "abc")))

val result = data
.leftOuterJoin(data2)
.filter(record => record._2._2 == None)

println(result.collect.toSeq)
Output> WrappedArray((168,(def,None)))
```

Comment: Thanks. In java, I have to transfer JavaRDD<Long> to a JavaPairRDD<Long, Long> (just add whatever as the second value), then do the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Dataframe API - RDD is old and does not have a lot of the optimisation of Tungsten engine - you can use an `antijoin` (it could exist also on RDD api, but let's use the good one ;-) )

```
val dataA = Seq((192, "abc"),(168, "def") ).toDF("MyLong", "MyString")
val dataB = Seq((192, "abc")).toDF.toDF("MyLong", "MyString")

dataA.join(dataB, Seq("MyLong"), "leftanti").show(false)

+------+--------+
|MyLong|MyString|
+------+--------+
|168   |def     |
+------+--------+
```